# Roslyn C# Code Generator

Tags: roslyn

I want to write a compiler or code generator that will read CI from compiled C# code assembly and return all the classes together with entire syntax tree.

How can I do this using Roslyn?

Comment: Your question is a little too broad as it is; give it a go yourself and see where you get stuck so you can ask a more specific question. You might also be interested in [this](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: That's a _decompiler_, which Roslyn isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Roslyn cannot take a compiled assembly and convert that back into source code. It's a compiler, not a decompiler.